# Error: package com.facebook.react.modules.storage does not exist - at try building react native App

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting this error when trying to build a React native App (npm run android)

error: package com.facebook.react.modules.storage does not exist
import com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier;

error: package com.facebook.react.modules.storage does not exist
com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setMaximumSize(size);

React Native 63

I've already tried to remove node_modules and install everything again but nothing works at the moment

Comment: i have same issues ,when i following instalation guide from documentation and try to running old project then error show like yours

Answer (score 1):

This was reported in rect-native bulletin, the issue started on Nov-4, 2022 and react-native team released a patch and workarounds.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

For your use of 63.x, update to the patch, 63.5 and it will fix the build, try clean and build.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210) adding folowing content to your `android/build.gradle` and after that sync project with gradle will fix the issue:

```js
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```